# Define the term energy density of a body under strain

Tags: elasticity

How to define energy density of a body in terms of strain? This was my past exam question. But I am unable to solve it.

Comment: It's the tensor product of stress and strain. Do you know how to get stress from strain?

Comment: yes. What is the good answer actually ?

Comment: $\epsilon:C:\epsilon$

Comment: I didn't get you.